# Spring custom sorting in Sort.of

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there any way to use `Sort.of` with this kind of sorting?

```
    @Query("SELECT l FROM Livestream l WHERE l.status IN ('LIVE', 'FUTURE') ORDER BY CASE WHEN l.status = 'LIVE' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END ASC")
    fun findLiveAndFuture(pageable: Pageable): Page<Livestream>
```

Comment: You can try `JpaSort.unsafe(ASC, "CASE WHEN l.status = 'LIVE' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END")`. Wouldn't simply sorting by `l.status` work, though?

Comment: @crizzis thanks! It works in that way `JpaSort.unsafe(ASC, "(CASE WHEN l.status = 'LIVE' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END)")`. About the query, I've just simplified it. The original query is more complicated and uses case in sorting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the usage of the `case` at the end since the result will most probably have both `LIVE` and `FUTURE` results, so the case won't work as expected.

You can use the object `Sort` in `Pageable` to define the sorting you want to have. This will require you to use something like [`PageRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort-) to achieve it.

Or you can use pass the `Sort` object in the repository, like so:

```
fun findLiveAndFuture(pageable: Pageable, sort: Sort): Page<Livestream>
```